# Can't get MYSQL to be visible from outside

Tags: centos, mysql

I know there's a lot of topics about this but i've read them all and still can't access MYSQL from outside... Any help will be apreciated

I'm using Centos 6.7.

This is my /etc/my.cnf:

bind-address = 0.0.0.0

This is the line I added to iptables and later saved:

sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

Restarted mysql and everything I can think of. Also flushed MYSQL PERMISSIONS. This is a capture of the mysql.user table:

[image]

AS stated any help is welcome, I've spent way too much time on this...

EDIT 1: The MYSQL Virtual Machine is visible and available to the computer trying to connect to it:

[image]

EDIT 2: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> sudo iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT

This is almost certainly your problem. The default firewall for CentOS would put that rule into the INPUT chain after the DROP all rule. This means that the rule is never acted upon.

Use `iptables  -I INPUT ...` to insert a rule into the beginning of your chain and you should be good to go.

Comment: Mmmm looks like I can't get the line after the DROP ALL to move up... :S

Comment: Thanks sir, that was a good catch. I've got a problem with permissions now but looks like the server is visible now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Run a command like below to access from all machines.

```
 mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Strange, I do mysql -u root -p (blank password) and when i execute your command I get the following error: access denied for user ''@'localhost' using password: no

Answer (score 1):

`nmap` it and you will see what ports are open. `ping` doesn't say much.

Comment: Updated in "edit 2"

Comment: The port is filtered. You need to open it. You can follow Iain's advice, if you know what you're doing and how to do it, or add a view of your iptables to your question.

Comment: You may also want to make sure you're configuring the right interface :-) `ifconfig`

Comment: Well, in fact filtered may mean it's open. It cannot be determined by nmap. So you may prefer to show the world your iptables.

Comment: Interface was okey and port was opened correctly but it was on the line after deny all. Moving it up solved it. Thanks